# Double head and hook arrow

Tags: arrows

It is quite easy to generate an arrow with a double head *and* a hooked tail using `tikz-cd`, but I would quite like a way to do this inline. I can't find a specific LaTeX command (I've read through a lot of those 'list of all symbols' lists). Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a hook arrow, back up and set a standard arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hookdoubleheadrightarrow}{%
  \hookrightarrow\mathrel{\mspace{-15mu}}\rightarrow
}

\begin{document}

$A \hookdoubleheadrightarrow B_{A \hookdoubleheadrightarrow B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Extensible version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hookdoubleheadrightarrow}{%
  \hookrightarrow\mathrel{\mspace{-15mu}}\rightarrow
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xhookdoubleheadrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \lhook\joinrel
  \ext@arrow 0359\rightarrowfill@ {#1}{#2}%
  \mathrel{\mspace{-15mu}}\rightarrow
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$A \hookdoubleheadrightarrow B_{A \hookdoubleheadrightarrow B}$

$A \xhookdoubleheadrightarrow{aaaaaa} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works just great as long as it doesn't have to be lengthened.  (i was sure this had been answered before, but i couldn;t find it.  don't worry, i gave it +1.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Piece of cake. `;-)`

Comment: yup.. stolen from `plain.tex` + `amscd.sty` no doubt.  (well, that's where *i* would have stolen it from.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Actually the inner part could simply be `\xrightarrow[#1]{#2}`

Comment: yup.  i think you may know `amsmath` better than i do.  (on the other hand, you actually use it; i only have to vet authors' problems.)