# What is a reasonable way to represent a bijective mapping?

Tags: symbols

Say I have a bijective function $f$, then if I wish to define a bijective mapping between two sets $A$ and $B$, I would need a reasonable notation to denote bijectivity. Usually for a mapping between two sets, one would use `\mapsto`. As for injectivity, surjectivity, or bijectivity there aren't any standard notation.

Comment: Definition copied from wikipedija: `The function $f\colon X\to Y$ is bijective, if for all $y\in Y$, there is a unique $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.`, i.e. as can be seen, they they use simple arrow obtained by `\to`.  How is your question related to LaTeX?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46678

Comment: Perhaps a double headed `\hookrightarrow` (we'd usually use `\hootrightarrow` to denote something `injective` and a double headed arrow for something surjective.

Comment: @Zarko `\to` and `\mapsto` don't seem a good way to represent a bijective mapping

Comment: @daleif thank you for your suggestion I will apply them

Comment: Your problem is not related to LaTeX! Please consult some other SE site, for example a link given in @campa comment!

Comment: Is there a double-headed hook arrow in some package? Detexify gives me nothing. (Or even a hoot-right arrow!)

Comment: Incidentally, daleif 's comment is what I would consider to be standard notation, so if you rephrase the question as to how to get a double-headed hook arrow then it is perfectly valid for this site (though may be a duplicate).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296152/15925 for at least one solution